# LazyLoading with LoadChildren in angular 4

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I want to lazy load a module with loadChildren

say

```
{ path: 'form', loadChildren: './form/form.module#FormModule' }
```

i just want to add this route but "form" folder is not present at this time( at the time of build). 
Now after the app is loaded on the client side, i add form folder on the file server under src/app, now i call "/form" from the url.

Will FormModule get loaded 
or 
this case is not possible and FormModule should compulsorily be present before the build for load children to work?

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking

Comment: @Maximus  i have rewritten the question. Is it understandable?

Comment: That won't work. Consider that there is very complex build process that won't leave anything like you see in your TypeScript sources and it can't do that when your FormModule is referenced but not present. However, creating components dynamically would probably work for your case.

Comment: @Matt the thing is i dont have the component/module when build happens. The component/module is generated on server side with templating engine while the app is served and used by the client. Now i want to use this module in my app. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: @Maximus i have an angular app. That app has a form builder via which i generate metaData(JSON) for the form.  This metaData is sent to the server. Now on server via templating engine i create a FormModule out of this metaData. Now i want to call this generated from the app. One way is to rebuild and republish the app. Is there any other way instead to rebuild of whole app?

Comment: how do you build your app? webpack, angular-cli?

Comment: angular-cli currently but it is a POC

Comment: no, you don't usually need to have the lazy loaded module available during the build. But angular-cli tries to package it into the package through AOT plugin it hooks into webpack process. so you either have to not use angular-cli or modify its `webpack.config.js` through `ng eject` but that's a pretty tricky process

Comment: @Maximus any reference to help me with this? and yeah i will try and get back to you.